# Weird query. Get the id from an other table

Tags: c#, mysql

What i want: I want to put the author id, but i only got the authors name. From the table author. So how can i get the author id, in this query below??

```
INSERT INTO book (title, isbn, author_id) VALUES('" + BookTitle.Text.ToString() + "', '" + BookIsbn.Text.ToString() + "', '(SELECT id FROM author WHERE first_name = '" + BookAuthor.Text.ToString() + "')')";
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Marijn')')' at line 1
```

I hope i make clear what i want.

Thank you!

Comment: try to run that query in LOINQPAD, and see what values you get and **get rid of the clear strings (in production code),  always use parameters in the query and not strings**.

Comment: please please please use query parameters!

Comment: I guess you are trying to execute some dynamic query here. Can you post the entire code line where this dynamic query is getting built?This will help us understand the syntax error more precisely.

Comment: building an sql query like that may lead to [sql injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) attacks, use parameters instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here you have to have function fn_getID(fname) which will return id.

"INSERT INTO book (title, isbn, author_id) 
VALUES('" + BookTitle.Text.ToString() + "', '" + BookIsbn.Text.ToString() + "'"+fn_getID(BookAuthor.Text.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put the second SELECT statement in single quotes (MySQL interprets this as a string).

```
"INSERT INTO book (title, isbn, author_id) 
VALUES ('" + BookTitle.Text.ToString() + "', '" + BookIsbn.Text.ToString() + "', 
    (SELECT id FROM author WHERE first_name = '" + BookAuthor.Text.ToString() + "'))"
```

PS Note that your method of inserting data into database makes it very vulnerable to an injection attack.

Comment: Yes i know, it's a school project. And the teacher was away, and we dind't get any code or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is **VERY** vulnerable to sql injection. The best way is to use parameterized query by using `SQLCommand and its parameters`. And I think it is better to use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` on your query

```
(
"
INSERT INTO book (title, isbn, authorID)
SELECT '" + BookTitle.Text.ToString() + "' as title,
       '" + BookIsbn.Text.ToString() + "' AS isbn,
       id  as authorID
FROM author 
WHERE first_name = '" + BookAuthor.Text.ToString() + "'
"
)
```

using `ADO.Net`

```
string query =  "INSERT INTO book (title, isbn, authorID)
                SELECT @title as title,
                       @isbn AS isbn,
                       id  as authorID
                FROM author 
                WHERE first_name = @author";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("connectionstringHere"))
{
    using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = query;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", BookTitle.Text.ToString());
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", BookIsbn.Text.ToString());
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", BookAuthor.Text.ToString());
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            // error here
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```